# Using multiple filters in v-for directive in Vue 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-filter

Just following a tutorial about [Vue filter on v-for directive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDQXrJTvTeE) in Vue 1.x,  the author was using multiple filters in one `v-for` directive, e.g.

`<ul v-for="post in posts | filterBy nameFilter in 'name' | filterBy catFilter in 'cat'"></ul>`

As far as I know from the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters-Outside-Text-Interpolations-removed), this syntax is no longer being used in Vue 2.0, I tried to rewrite this line of code into

`<ul v-for="post in nameFilter | catFilter"></ul>`

I also created two computed functions `nameFilter` and `cateFilter` to filter out the posts by name and category. My code is not working, it only listens to the first filter which is `nameFilter`, `cateFilter` has no effect at all.

So I was wondering in Vue 2.0, is that still possible to add multiple filters in `v-for` directive? If it is possible, could you guys please advise the syntax?

If that's impossible, does that mean that I need to create one filter function to do all the filter logic in that single function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer from [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuejs-multiple-filterby-values?page=1)

Basically, we only need one computed function to return the filtered data for `v-for` directive, e.g.

`<ul v-for="post in filteredPosts"></ul>`

If we want to add multiple, just chain all your javascript native `.filter` functions in that function and return the data. In my case, it would be something like this:

```
computed: {
    filteredPost: function () {
        var self = this
        return self.posts
            .filter(function (post) {
                return post.title.indexOf(self.searchQuery) !== -1;
            })
            .filter(function(post) {
                return (post.category.includes(self.selectedCategory))
            })
    }
}
```

`self.searchQuery` and `self.selectedCategory` are just data properties for this Vue instance in my example, the key takeaway is **one computed function with multiple `.filter()` functions chaining together.**

Hope that will help.